# ruby get array details and modify it from running process

Tags: ruby

I have ruby script running which has array and hash variable values. Is there any way to get the array details of the running ruby script process and change its value without killing the current running process?

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: please provide more specifics and maybe even some code